# Analytic count over partition with and without ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I don't understand why there are different results when using an `ORDER BY` clause in an analytic `COUNT` function.

Using a simple example:

```
with req as
 (select 1 as n, 'A' as cls
    from dual
  union
  select 2 as n, 'A' as cls
    from dual)
select req.*, count(*) over(partition by cls) as cnt from req;
```

gives the the following result:

```
N   CLS CNT
2   A   2
1   A   2
```

Whereas, when adding an `ORDER BY` in the analytic clause, the result is different!

```
with req as
 (select 1 as n, 'A' as cls
    from dual
  union
  select 2 as n, 'A' as cls
    from dual)
select req.*, count(*) over(partition by cls order by n) as cnt from req;
```

CNT column changed:

```
N   CLS CNT
1   A   1
2   A   2
```

Can someone explain please?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) to docs. It's somewhat obscure, however.

Analytic clause consists of `query_partition_clause`, `order_by_clause` and `windowing_clause`. And, a really important thing about `windowing_clause` is

> You cannot specify this clause unless you have specified the
>   `order_by_clause`. Some window boundaries defined by the `RANGE` clause
>   let you specify only one expression in the `order_by_clause`. Refer to
>   "Restrictions on the ORDER BY Clause".

But not only can you not use `windowing_clause` without the `order_by_clause`, they are tied together.

> If you omit the windowing_clause entirely, then the default is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

The default windowing clause produces something like running total. `COUNT` returns `1` for first row, as there is only one row between the top of the window and the current row, `2` for the second row and so on.

So in your first query there is *no* windowing at all, but there is the default windowing in the second one.

And you can simulate the behavior of the first query by specifying fully unbounded window.

```
with req as
 (select 1 as n, 'A' as cls
    from dual
  union
  select 2 as n, 'A' as cls
    from dual)
select req.*, count(*) over(partition by cls order by n RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as cnt from req;
```

Yep

```
N   CLS CNT
1   A   2
2   A   2
```

Comment: The default windowing clause produces a "running count" only in the special case when the ORDER BY clause produces a total ordering (with no ties). The default window clause uses `RANGE between...` rather than `ROWS between...` - so rows where the `ORDER BY` measure is the same will have the same `COUNT` as well. To get a true "running count" in these cases, one needs to add an explicit windowing clause, `ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row`. Other than that, nice answer!

Comment: That's a very good call, thanks. I thought about it and wrote "something like running total" as I didn't want to get into this `RANGE/ROWS` thing. Especially since it's covered well in the docs. I guess I should have though, but you've provided a very nice and clear explanation in your answer, so I'm gonna leave it at that.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to think about this - leaving the `ORDER BY` out is equivalent to "ordering" in a way that all rows in the partition are "equal" to each other. Indeed, you can get the same effect by explicitly adding the `ORDER BY` clause like this:  `ORDER BY 0` (or "order by" *any* constant expression), or even, more emphatically, `ORDER BY NULL`.

Why you get the `COUNT()` or `SUM()` etc. for the entire partition has to do with the default windowing clause: `RANGE between unbounded preceding and current row`. "Range" (as opposed to "ROWS") means all rows "tied" with the current row are also included, even if they don't precede it. Since all rows are tied, this means the entire partition is included, no matter which row is "current."

Comment: Nicely explained!!

Comment: For me, once using order by, it sounds like using nested "partition by". Is this correct in any way?

Comment: @DINATAKLIT - no.

Comment: Why not? Coz once I ran an example with partition by the account_id order by the occurred month it sums up regarding the month once I omit it it sum up only regarding the account_id so that's why I said it's partition inside partition once we use order by another column. Does not this, in this case, make a scene, Does it?

Answer (score 2):

Window functions will perform the aggregation over partition by (split by) value, when you omit `ORDER BY` clause the result will be similar to `GROUP BY` with output of each row . It is also possible to omit `PARTITION BY`, in which case there is just one partition containing all the rows

When you add `ORDER BY` clause to window function then it will perform the calculation in subsequent order within the same partition and start over with a different partition (group of values)

Values that are not distinct in the `ORDER BY` ordering are said to be peers, in `COUNT()` they will have the same calculated result of its last peer that will create gaps that maintain the total